# Strange behavior when splitting an AVR program across functions

Tags: avr, atmega328p

I'm trying to run a very basic "blinker" program on an Atmega328P. Here it is in its entirety:

```
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <util/delay.h> 
#include <avr/interrupt.h>

void setup() {
    DDRC |= (1<<PC2);
}

int main(void) {
    setup();
    while (1) {
        PORTC |= (1<<PC2);
        _delay_ms(1000); 
        PORTC &= ~(1<<PC2);
        _delay_ms(1000); 
    }
    return 0;
}
```

If I try building and installing this:

```
avr-gcc -Wall -Os -mmcu=atmega328p -DF_CPU=16000000UL  -c transmitter.c -o transmitter.o
avr-gcc -o transmitter.elf transmitter.o
avr-objcopy -O ihex -R .eeprom transmitter.elf transmitter.hex
avr-size --format=avr --mcu=atmega328p transmitter.elf
avrdude -F -V -patmega328p -cstk500v1 -P/dev/cu.usbmodem1D11401 -b19200 -Uflash:w:transmitter.hex:i
```

nothing happens. However, if I move the contents of `setup()` into `main()`, everything works fine (LED blinks as expected):

```
int main(void) {
    DDRC |= (1<<PC2);
    while (1) {
        PORTC |= (1<<PC2);
        _delay_ms(1000); 
        PORTC &= ~(1<<PC2);
        _delay_ms(1000); 
    }
    return 0;
}
```

In terms of schematics, it's a basic 3.3V circuit with an LED connected to a 15ohm resistor on PC2. I have no reason to suspect the circuit itself, as it works fine if I write and install a similar program using Arduino Studio.

Any suggestions?

**UPDATE** Added `avrdude` command line in its entirety above. It's worth noting that I get no errors at all from `avrdude` - everything succeeds.

Comment: Show the linker map file or the generated assembly. You might be missing the MCU startup code.

Comment: Which compiler? As in where was it downloaded from? I’m suspecting you might need some more magic in the linker commands, but has been years since I’ve touched avr-gcc at this level.

Comment: @Kartman It's from `homebrew`:
`brew tap osx-cross/avr && brew install avr-gcc`

Comment: @Justme how would I go about doing this? Sorry, but I'm not very familiar with debugging on a low level

Comment: @Mellivar. Might be better to use the one that comes with an Arduino install. Or platformio. Have a look at what Arduino uses on the cmdline to ensure you have the right magic.

Comment: what is your question? ... what do you want to know? ... if you are asking what to try next, then you could put all blink code in `setup()` to see if setup is actually called

Comment: @Melllvar This is not about low level debugging, but about telling the compiler, or rather the linker how to build the executable properly. You did not even tell the linking stage to which MCU you are targeting. You might want to read avr-gcc and avr-libc manuals or tutorials how to compile and link properly.

Comment: @Justme that was it, I was missing the --mmcu flag for the linker! Feel free to add your comment as answer, and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Also the linker needs to know for which MCU to generate the binary, to be able to include the correct startup code library for your specific MCU model. Add it to the command line that links the output binary.